# Include a picture Excel

Tags: excel

I must include in a Excel-Sheet an image like *.gif.

Who can help me?

Comment: @skaffman: You removed the `rpgle` tag, was this really not about it afterall?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an image to a sheet in Excel using the pull down menu.
Insert -> Picture -> From File

Not really a questions for developers, perhaps you need to clarify what you are doing..

Comment: I think he needs to use RPGLE, as the tag indicates.